# Abbreviation for introducing a problem statement

Tags: notation, terminology

I'm not entirely sure this is an adequate question on this site since it's not a mathematical but rather a language-related one, but I've been wondering about this for a while. I'm sure we all agree that when presenting a mathematical proof, one should first clearly state the statement to be shown.

In German, one uses the conventional notation is "z.z.:" to indicate that the problem statement begins, which is short for "zu zeigen" = "to be shown". It's a useful little abbreviation and I was wondering if anything similar exists in conventional mathematical notation in English, since I haven't come across anything like it yet.

Comment: Not that I can think of, not in  widespread use.

Comment: Why not just say something like "I will demonstrate that" or "We will demonstrate that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *wts* for *want to show* and *nts* for *need to show*, but they are not as common as *zz* in German and perhaps even more informal.

They both appear in [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon) on mathematical jargon.